# How to Access in App.Path?

Tags: vb6

When I run this code in VB, the VB said me "Patch file access error". Can anybody help me? Here is my code:

```
MkDir App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2)
Open App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2) & "\pass.txt" For Append As #1
Print #1, Splice(3)
Close #1
MkDir App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2)
Open App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2) & "\list.txt" For Append As #1
Print #1, "" 'we have to put something into the buddy list
                 'so well put nothing ;)
Close #1
MkDir App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2)
Open App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2) & "\info.txt" For Append As #1
Print #1, "" 'we have to put something into the buddy list
                 'so well put nothing ;)
Close #1
MkDir App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2)
Open App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2) & "\ipreglog.log" For Append As #1
Print #1, inip
Close #1
```

Comment: You know my answer to this question is also in one of your previous very similar questions.

Comment: Step through your code in debug mode and indicate at exactly which line of code you get the error.

Comment: @Baaner  in this line MkDir App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2)

Comment: @ Pars App - I assume the directory does not already exist since you are now checking for it. Add "Debug.Print App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2)" (without the quotes), command before the MkDir command and make sure you have a valid path. If the path has a space in it you must enclose the entire path in double quotes.

Comment: What OS are you running this in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to create (MkDir) a directory that already exists you will get an error 75, Path/File access error. You need to modify your code to check for the directory and create it only if it does not exist.

```
If Len(Dir(App.Path & "\users" & Splice(2)) = 0 Then
    MkDir App.Path & "\users" & Splice(2)
End If
```

etc.

Comment: @Pars - You have accepted this as the answer so how did you solve your error? Please leave some information for others so they can benefit from you experience.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that your process doesn't have the necessary permissions on the path to create a directory? By default Users do have modify privileges on c:\Users

You can get this issue on Windows 7 if you haven't elevated your process using `Run As Administrator`. This is true for the VB6 IDE as well as this doesn't run as admin by default.